# How align 3 cards on the same row

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, card

I want 3 cards to display in the picture below

[image]

However, I dont know what wrong with my code below: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-glitter-cge8r?file=/src/App.js. Can someone give me help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix using `flex` box:

Output:

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import {
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardText,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  CardFooter
} from "reactstrap";

import avatar from "./Original3.JPG";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex"
      }}
    >
      <div class="col-4">
        <Card
          style={{
            padding: "5px"
          }}
        >
          <CardImg top width="100%" src={avatar} alt="Card image cap" />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>3D</CardTitle>
            <CardText>web application</CardText>
          </CardBody>
          <CardFooter>
            <small className="text-muted">Last updated 1 ago</small>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <Card
          style={{
            padding: "5px"
          }}
        >
          <CardImg top width="100%" src={avatar} alt="Card image cap" />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>3D</CardTitle>
            <CardText>web application</CardText>
          </CardBody>
          <CardFooter>
            <small className="text-muted">Last updated 1 ago</small>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <Card
          style={{
            padding: "5px"
          }}
        >
          <CardImg top width="100%" src={avatar} alt="Card image cap" />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>3D</CardTitle>
            <CardText>web application</CardText>
          </CardBody>
          <CardFooter>
            <small className="text-muted">Last updated 1 ago</small>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-dawn-fkcvk?file=/src/App.js:0-1667)

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply style on parent div of cards just like

```
<div class="row" style={{display:'flex',flexWrap:'noWrap'}}>
```